# sendmail (postfix) stopped delivering mails

Tags: debian, postfix, sendmail

how can I find out why postfix / sendmail stopped delivering mail? I tried to sendmail from the console, no errors showed but it has been nothing delivered... the same when by using mail() in php.. (which is using sendmail)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked your queue and logs?

Comment: Which do you have: Sendmail or Postfix?  The answers vary according to which software is actually in use.

Comment: @JdeBP: I assume he is using Postfix and access it using the sendmail binary which is shipped with it to be compatible to the old mothership :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into the mail logs, typically in `/var/log/mail.log` or similar. Also check your queue using `postqueue -p`. And of course check the obvious stuff (server running, enough disk-space, working network / firewall, ...)

Also check your mailserver's configuration, if it is really correctly configured to directly send mail or to forward them to some smarthost. In your logs you should see if something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything possible... reinstalled the postfix, changed to old sendmail, checked for errors... lost hours and hours with no luck. Solution: I moved to a new server and dumped the old one. 1 hour work and no guess work :) thanks anyway guys.

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue.  Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.